# MongoDB aggregate count is too much slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have around 60 thousand document in `users` collection, and have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {"$match":{"userType":"employer"}},
    {"$lookup":{"from":"companies","localField":"_id","foreignField":"owner.id","as":"company"}},
    {"$unwind":"$company"},
    {"$lookup":{"from":"companytypes","localField":"company.type.id","foreignField":"_id","as":"companyType"}},
    {"$unwind":"$companyType"},
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

It takes around 12 seconds to count, even I call count function before list function, but my list function with `limit: 10` response faster than count.

And following is `explain` result:

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "userType" : "employer"
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "company" : 1,
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "jobs.users",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "userType" : {
                            "$eq" : "employer"
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "userType" : {
                                "$eq" : "employer"
                            }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "companies",
                "as" : "company",
                "localField" : "_id",
                "foreignField" : "owner.id",
                "unwinding" : {
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "$nor" : [ 
                    {
                        "company" : {
                            "$eq" : []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "$const" : null
                },
                "total" : {
                    "$sum" : {
                        "$const" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : false,
                "total" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: The query is not using any index, have you tried indexing `companyName`?

Comment: @Paizo I have indexed both `users`, and `companies` collections with full text search

Comment: ok, but your explain plain specify that no index is used `"indexFilterSet" : false,`; Anyway I think the `$lookup` is the killing part

Comment: Post a sample document from your `users` and `companies` collections and your expected output.

Comment: @Paizo Yeah when I remove lookup from query, its ok, but with lookup its slow. I need lookup in my query.

Comment: @jones if you use the `$lookup` make sure you have an index for the  `foreignField` attributes.

Comment: @Paizo Thank you, its working now.

Comment: Glad it helped, I added a little more elaborated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$lookup` operations are slow since they mimic the left join behavior, from the [DOCS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

> $lookup performs an equality match on the localField to the
>   foreignField from the documents of the from collection

Hence if there are no indexes in the fields used for `joining` the collections Mongodb is force to do a collection scan.

Adding an index for the `foreignField` attributes should prevent a collection scan and increase the performance even of a magnitude